# Automatically sleep and wake-up at specific times

Tags: hibernate, sleep

How can I hibernate or sleep my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop and have it "wake up" the next day?

I have seen software that can do this on windows, so it can't be hard on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### *rtcwake*

The command that you are interested in is `rtcwake`:

> This  program  is  used  to  enter a system sleep state until specified wakeup time.

### testing

To find the correct syntax that works for you try the following:

```
sudo rtcwake -u -s 60 -m mem
```

This should suspend the computer for 60 seconds before restoring.  The significant parameter is `mem`  You have several options you can choose - play to find the value that works best for you:

```
          standby
                 ACPI state S1. This state offers  minimal,  though  real,
                 power savings, while providing a very low-latency transi‐
                 tion back to a working system. This is the default mode.

          mem    ACPI state S3 (Suspend-to-RAM). This state offers signif‐
                 icant  power  savings  as everything in the system is put
                 into a low-power  state,  except  for  memory,  which  is
                 placed in self-refresh mode to retain its contents.

          disk   ACPI  state  S4  (Suspend-to-disk). This state offers the
                 greatest power savings, and  can  be  used  even  in  the
                 absence  of  low-level platform support for power manage‐
                 ment. This state operates  similarly  to  Suspend-to-RAM,
                 but  includes  a final step of writing memory contents to
                 disk.

          off    ACPI  state  S5  (Poweroff).  This  is  done  by  calling
                 '/sbin/shutdown'.   Not officially supported by ACPI, but
                 usually working.

          no     Don't suspend. The rtcwake command sets RTC  wakeup  time
                 only.

          on     Don't  suspend,  but  read  RTC  device  until alarm time
                 appears. This mode is useful for debugging.
```

### suspend until a known time

A script (at the bottom of this post) could be used to suspend your computer and wake at a specific time:

syntax is `suspend_until [hh:mm]` for example

```
sudo ./suspend_until 07:30
```

Save the script as the name `suspend_until` and give it execute rights i.e.

```
chmod +x suspend_until
```

### Cron

You can create a root cron job that calls this script to execute at a specific time in the evening and then awake in the morning:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Now enter something like to run the suspend script at 23:30:

```
30 23 * * * /home/myhomefolder/suspend_until 07:30
```

### suspend_until script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Auto suspend and wake-up script
#
# Puts the computer on standby and automatically wakes it up at specified time
#
# Written by Romke van der Meulen <redge.online@gmail.com>
# Minor mods fossfreedom for AskUbuntu
#
# Takes a 24hour time HH:MM as its argument
# Example:
# suspend_until 9:30
# suspend_until 18:45

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Argument check
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: suspend_until HH:MM"
    exit
fi

# Check whether specified time today or tomorrow
DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"`))
NOW=$((`date +%s`))
if [ $DESIRED -lt $NOW ]; then
    DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"` + 24*60*60))
fi

# Kill rtcwake if already running
sudo killall rtcwake

# Set RTC wakeup time
# N.B. change "mem" for the suspend option
# find this by "man rtcwake"
sudo rtcwake -l -m mem -t $DESIRED &

# feedback
echo "Suspending..."

# give rtcwake some time to make its stuff
sleep 2

# then suspend
# N.B. dont usually require this bit
#sudo pm-suspend

# Any commands you want to launch after wakeup can be placed here
# Remember: sudo may have expired by now

# Wake up with monitor enabled N.B. change "on" for "off" if 
# you want the monitor to be disabled on wake
xset dpms force on

# and a fresh console
clear
echo "Good morning!"
```

N.B.

Change `mem` in this part of the script for whatever suspend method works for you:

```
# Set RTC wakeup time
sudo rtcwake -l -m mem -t $DESIRED &
```

You may also have to substitute the `-u` flag in place of the `-l` flag depending on whether your hardware clock uses UTC (`-u`) or local (`-l`) time.  Note that your hardware clock is different from the system clock you see in your operating system.

credit to [redgeonline](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10878570&postcount=36)

Comment: what I asked for... and so much more! Thank you for reading in between the lines!

Comment: thanks - just slightly updated to highlight which bit of the script you need to change for whatever suspend method works for you.

Comment: The killall is unnecessary, rtcwake doesn't run as a daemon, it simply writes a value to /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm; running it again will write another value to that file. Also, remove the & at the end of rtcwake, it will exit when it's done. Then you can remove the sleep command. And, if you want to run other root commands in the script, why not run the whole thing sudo instead of individual commands there?

Comment: # my old laptop would not wake up using the script above .  so this is what i did
# root crontab 
30 20 * * * /home/gare/Documents/scripts/suspend_10_hours.sh >> /home/gare/Documents/scripts/suspend.log



~$ more /home/gare/Documents/scripts/suspend_10_hours.sh
#!/bin/bash
# old laptop will not wake;  so tell rtcwake to suspend for 10 hours 
# 10 hours * 60 mins * 60 secs =36000
sudo rtcwake -u -s 36000 -m mem

Comment: In addition to what @unhammer said, killall is not only unnecessary but actually harmful because it will send SIGTERM to all processes on your system that match "killall". Please incorporate the fixes suggested by unhammer instead of leading to people copying wrong practice.

Comment: " depending on whether your hardware clock uses UTC (`-u`) or local (`-l`) time" - It isn't directly obvious how to determine this. Although I suspect pretty much everyone except those in the UK / GMT will probably want to use `-l`. `sudo hwclock --show` won't obviously tell you, although I guess it will say UTC in their somewhere if you need to use UTC.

Answer (score 5):

Using rtcwake I have created a simple bash script. It uses php to translate natural language into system time. For example:

- `sudo ./cu "tomorrow 9am"`
- `sudo ./cu "next monday 3pm"`
- `sudo ./cu "1 hour ago"`

  `rtcwake: time doesn't go backward`

[You can download it here.](https://github.com/albertolopez/cu)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export sdate=$1

date=`/usr/bin/php << 'EOF'
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT-2");
$date = strtotime(GETENV("sdate"));
echo "\r".$date;
EOF`

rtcwake -m mem -t $date
```

Comment: Note that date -d already understands several such strings: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html

Answer (score 0):

`rtcwake` had no effect on my machine.  On my Asus motherboard, I had to set the wake time in the bios.  I found the setting under Advanced > APM menu and I had to use UTC even though my bios time is set to US Eastern time.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome command, thanks for sharing.  I added a little more so it sleeps at 11pm and wakes at 8am:

```
sudo until [[ $(date +%H:%M) == 23:00 ]]; do sleep 2; done; rtcwake -u -s 32400 -m mem
```

Comment: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`

Answer (score 0):

For others who ended up at this question searching for how to simply suspend/hibernate after a certain amount of time (and not automatically wake), this seems to work on ubuntu 22.04

`sleep 3600 && systemctl suspend`

Where 3600 is the number of seconds to wait before suspending.