# Rtcwake based script not working as cronjob

Tags: suspend, cron

I'm trying to use the following wake script, which I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times), to put my computer to sleep at night and wake it in the morning. The script uses **rtcwake**:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Auto suspend and wake-up script
#
# Puts the computer on standby and automatically wakes it up at specified time
#
# Written by Romke van der Meulen <redge.online@gmail.com>
# Minor mods fossfreedom for AskUbuntu
#
# Takes a 24hour time HH:MM as its argument
# Example:
# suspend_until 9:30
# suspend_until 18:45

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Argument check
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: suspend_until HH:MM"
    exit
fi

# Check whether specified time today or tomorrow
DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"`))
NOW=$((`date +%s`))
if [ $DESIRED -lt $NOW ]; then
    DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"` + 24*60*60))
fi

# Kill rtcwake if already running
sudo killall rtcwake

# Set RTC wakeup time
# N.B. change "mem" for the suspend option
# find this by "man rtcwake"
sudo rtcwake -l -m mem -t $DESIRED &

# feedback
echo "Suspending..."

# give rtcwake some time to make its stuff
sleep 2

# then suspend
# N.B. dont usually require this bit
#sudo pm-suspend

# Any commands you want to launch after wakeup can be placed here
# Remember: sudo may have expired by now

# Wake up with monitor enabled N.B. change "on" for "off" if 
# you want the monitor to be disabled on wake
xset dpms force on

# and a fresh console
clear
echo "Good morning!"
```

The script works alright when I run it manually from the command line, but when run as a cronjob, it never puts the computer down. The crontab command is here:

```
02 10 * * * /home/***/bin/suspend_until 10:03 >> /home/ethan/log/suspend.log 2>$1
```

The log is empty so I can't exactly tell what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put the job into the root crontab? `sudo crontab -e` , not `crontab -e` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use sudo: `sudo crontab -e'`