# How can I set a task to wake my computer up, after shutdown?

Tags: wakeup

I`m using Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to power on my computer by creating a task just like wake up my phone by setting alarm in Nokia phones,Can i do this in Linux Systems?

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have the option wake on LAN option in BIOS if so you can..

Comment: If you only want to wake up your computer after a certain time (without a phone) you can use [rtcwake](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From any device with internet access you can wake-up your machine from internet or LAN (if enabled in BIOS and forwarded properly trough a router, if any) by means of magic packet. The proper *wake up event* must be enable in bios for a desired suspend state like S3/S4.

- [**http://www.wakeonlan.me/**](http://www.wakeonlan.me/)

[image]

> - **`wakeonlan`**  (Linux command line) A tool to send a Wake-On-LAN "Magic Packet"

`sudo apt-get install etherwake`

`wakeonlan -i ipaddress`

> - **[Wol, Wake On Lan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benfinnigan.wol)** Android

[image]

or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mafro.android.wakeonlan&hl=en)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After shutdown, your computer is off. So nothing can happen with it, unless you press the power button manually.

Of course, they may be some alternative like **Wake-on-LAN** capabilities if supported by your BIOS. This is a mechanism by which specific packets are sent to a powered off computer (but of course still connected to a power source and an Ethernet network) to power it on.

Obviously, this has to be done from a source external to your computer.

Unfortunately, not all BIOS and network adapters support Wake-on-LAN

More info about [Wake-on-LAN at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I don't think so. Linux system are booting and shutting down more complicated than the java-language made os that Nokia used to use (Now it produces only smartphones with windows, android and symbian). So, sorry but I don't think that you can make it.

Comment: as he sais..can't do

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box option:

If your PC's BIOS supports the option of booting when AC power is applied, you can select this option, then use a power outlet timer to apply power to the PC at the desired time.