# How to use the rtcwake command

Tags: command-line

I would like to get my `rtcwake` command to wake my computer from sleep at `06:00` the following day.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +\%s -d "tomorrow 06:00")
```

So far it isn't waking. Any ideas?

Comment: posted this for me.  I have it in a cronjob and the going to sleep part works but it never wakes up.  I have to manually wake it and when i do that the computer says the time is still the time that it went to sleep.

Comment: @basketball I am not sure I get this right, ryanlee posted this for you?

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes

Comment: @basketball does the sudo work for you? If not, I'll remove the answer, if it does, would you ask ryanlee to accept the answer? otherwise it will continue to appear as unanswered.

Comment: @JacobVlijm no it does not work. are you in #ubuntu?

Comment: @basketball you could try the -m disk option if your system doesn't support the -m mem option (which is not uncommon). The command needs sudo anyway. Sorry, I missed the #ubuntu.

Comment: @JacobVlijm can we chat on #ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Following link already has your answer:
[Automatically sleep and wake-up at specific times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times)

Also, you can check more about `rtcwake` using following:

1. Press, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type in, `$ man rtcwake`

Comment: that didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but in order for rtcwake to work inside of cronjob, you must run sudo crontab -e and then paste`sudo rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +\%s -d "tomorrow 06:00")`.