# I/O Errors (filesystem readonly) after wake with rtcwake

Tags: read-only, wakeup, rtc

I am trying to schedule the uptime of my server (it's in my bedroom) with rtcwake. The sleeping and waking gives no problems. But after waking the filesystem is set to readonly and I constantly get I/O errors. Thats not workable.

I'm using the command `sudo rtcwake -u -s 60 -m mem` and also tried it with the script from [Automatically sleep and wake-up at specific times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times)

Does anybody have a solution/workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It happens here too with -m mem.
The only solution was to set -m off, this works for me but, is state S5 and on after -s seconds. -m disk also gives errors and default -m is standby and is nothing here.