# 20.04 Suspend Issue - Going into a state of limbo

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, xfce, rtc

I've upgraded 20.04 and been having some issues with the suspend. I was using a modified version of the script [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times) on 18.04 with no issues. When I've upgraded to 20.04 I seem to have hit an issue with rtcwake and systemctl suspend.

What happens is when the PC reboots from suspend on time with whatever's scheduled, I'm faced with a black screen, with no interaction possible through the keyboard, ssh or over the network. It just hangs in a limbo state - while also occasionally ramping up the fans - until I force it off and on again, where it comes back fine.

I tired tinkering with the script, the system clocks and a few other places with no success. But as I'm fairly new to linux, I'm not quite sure where I should be looking to find the problem.

I'm using xfce4 btw.